# Connecting to hazelcast server from hazelcast client

Tags: java, client-server, javabeans, remote-server, hazelcast

I have the hazelcast server running with the config as follows,

```
Config config = new Config();

// **MapConfig**

config.setMapConfigs(getMapConfig());

// **Serialization factory**

config.setSerializationConfig(getSerializableFactory());
```

In this case, When hazelcast server is running in remote machine, I have to connect to my hazelcast server from hazelcast client.

But when I try to connect via Hazelcast client,

```
ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
clientConfig.getNetworkConfig().addAddress(IP:PORT);
```

Am able to connect to Hazelcast server,

But when I get map `hazelcast.getMap(test).values()` It shows the exception that it is expecting my configuration of seralization factory in hazelcast client config,

So When I add the serialization config which has Serialization factory class pointing to beans

```
clientConfig.setSerializationConfig(getSerializableFactory());
```

It works fine,

So Is there a way that I can connect to Hazelcast server without using Serialization Config.
The reason is If there is any change happening in beans which I will update in hazelcast server (In remote location), I have to update that in my hazelcast client too.

Thanks and Regards,
Harry

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your classes use custom serialization and thus require that factory. I use Spring instead of runtime configuration, and I didn't have to configure serialization - until I started using an optimized Portable instead of Java's standard Serializable.

Switching to Serializable will solve your problem, but custom serialization is good - twice as faster than java.io.Serializable. Unfortunately you need to configure it.

BTW this applies to any Hazelcast configuration. It should be exactly the same everywhere across the cluster. Maybe one day they'll remove that requirement for the thin client. How would you implement something like this? One reason to use Spring or Hazelcast's own XML - to put it in some shared location or include in every JAR/WAR via Maven.

You touched another issue here: versioning and compatibility. Generally I'd avoid different versions of the same class on different cluster nodes. Though Hazelcast can handle it with custom serialization (Portable if I am not mistaken).

In any case have one XML config or one base class (method, whatever) with the initializing code if you insist on doing it in Java. Put it in some JAR, reference it everywhere (as Maven dependency), problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

It is key to know the order in which Hazelcast tries to identify the serialization type of the object

When Hazelcast serializes an object:

1. It first checks whether the object is null.
2. If the above check fails, then Hazelcast checks if it is an instance
   of com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.DataSerializable or
   com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.IdentifiedDataSerializable.
3. If the above check fails, then Hazelcast checks if it is an instance
   of com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.Portable.
4. If the above check fails, then Hazelcast checks if it is an instance
   of one of the default types (see the Serialization chapter
   introduction for default types).
5. If the above check fails, then Hazelcast looks for a user-specified
   Custom Serializer, i.e. an implementation of ByteArraySerializer or
   StreamSerializer. Custom serializer is searched using the input
   Object’s Class and its parent class up to Object. If parent class
   search fails, all interfaces implemented by the class are also
   checked (excluding java.io.Serializable and java.io.Externalizable).
6. If the above check fails, then Hazelcast checks if it is an instance
   of java.io.Serializable or java.io.Externalizable and a Global
   Serializer is not registered with Java Serialization Override
   feature.
7. If the above check fails, Hazelcast uses the registered Global
   Serializer if one exists.
8. If all of the above checks fail, then serialization fails. When a
   class implements multiple interfaces, the above steps are important
   to determine the serialization mechanism that Hazelcast uses. **When a
   class definition is required for any of these serializations, you
   need to have all the classes needed by the application on your
   classpath because Hazelcast does not download them automatically,
   unless you are using user code deployment.**

For further information please refer to reference manual [Here](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/index.html#serialization)